# What is the correct way to have a member function return type be a superclass of the actual object you want to return?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

## The Question

What is the correct way to have a member function return type be a superclass of the actual object you wan to return ?.

## The Problem

Clang tidy warns me that returning `subClassA` or `subClassB` discards my override for `myMethod`. I also, get no output - presumably because I've accidently discarded the overrided `myMethod`.

## The Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SuperClass {
public :
    SuperClass() {
        cout << "I'm the superclass" << endl;
    };

    virtual std::string myMethod();
};

class SubClassA : public SuperClass {
public:
    SubClassA() : SuperClass() {
        cout << "I'm subclass A" << endl;
    }

    std::string myMethod() override {
        return "A";
    }
};

class SubClassB : public SuperClass {
public:
    SubClassB() : SuperClass() {
        cout << "I'm subclass B" << endl;
    }

    std::string myMethod() override {
        return "B";
    }
};

class Client {
private:
    std::string which;

    SuperClass letterFactory(){
        if (which == "A") {
            SubClassA subClassA;
            return subClassA;
        } else if (which == "B") {
            SubClassB subClassB;
            return subClassB;
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bad");
        }
    }

public:
    explicit Client(std::string &which) : which(which) {
        letterFactory();
    };
};

int main() {
    Client client();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Your `Client` constructor is actually creating and then discarding a `SuperClass` instance, which is actually suffering from slicing because you are returning by value.

Comment: What do you expect the call to `letterFactory` to accomplish?

Comment: Please, consider forming the question in a more legible way.

Comment: @AndyG This is my attempt at abstracting my poker hand evaluator into a MWE. In reality, the `letterFactory` will call each hand type class which is derived from a `Hand` and return the best hand that can be made (i.e. pair two pair etc).

Comment: @shargors Personally I think the question is legible, but always willing to take tips if you think it can be improved?

Comment: This question seems fine to me. I don't see why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning the derived class objects you are creating in `letterFactory`. Instead you are returning a base class object as a sliced copy of the derived class object that you declared in the function.

Calling `myMethod` on this returned object will call the implementation in `SuperClass`, because its most-derived type will be `SuperClass`.

Polymorphism only works on pointers and references. If you want your class to return either of the derived class types, it cannot return by-value. You can return a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<SuperClass> letterFactory(){
    if (which == "A") {
        return std::make_unique<SubClassA>();
    } else if (which == "B") {
        return std::make_unique<SubClassB>();
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Bad");
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant link : [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: Hi @walnut, thanks for the answer - knew it would be something to do with pointers. Would you mind elaborating on what `std::make_unique` is doing here?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh `std::make_unique` dynamically allocates and creates an object of the given type for you and puts it under control of a `std::unique_ptr` instance which it then returns. That way, you don't have to write `return std::unique_ptr<SubClassA>{new SubClassA};` which is cumbersome as it repeats the type name twice, requires use of `new` which should be discouraged where possible, and also is easier to make mistakes with especially with regards to exception safety.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)